# AT commands for GSM

Tags: pic, gsm, at-commands

I'am trying to interface a GSM module with flowcode for PIC and the [Tutorial](http://www.studentcompanion.co.za/interfacing-gsm-gprs-modem-with-pic-microcontroller-flowcode/) I'am following suggests a module [SmartGM862](http://www.mikroe.com/add-on-boards/gsm-gprs/smartgm862/) which is not available in my market but instead some other SIM900 series module development board are available.

My question is can I interface sim900 series module with flowcode and work with the same built-in AT command macros ?.

Do all GSM modules in general have same set of  AT commands? , so in that case any module should work with flowcode compatible AT commands.

Answer (score 1):

Basic Hayes AT commands are usually the same at every module. But there could be many differences because of different reasons.

1. There are always some manufacturer specific AT command group. For example at the [SIM900](ftp://imall.iteadstudio.com/IM120417009_IComSat/DOC_SIM900_AT%20Command%20Manual_V1.03.pdf), "Commands Special for SIMCOM". Mostly these are for controlling additional, non-standardized features.
2. Standardized AT commands. There are different ITU Telecom, GSM standards about AT commands. For example( at SIM900 "AT commands according to GSM07.05"):

   - [V.25.ter ITU-T recommendation](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.25ter-199504-S!Sup/en)
   - [GSM07.05](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gts/07/0705/05.05.00_60/gsmts_0705v050500p.pdf)
   - [GSM07.07](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gts/07/0707/05.00.00_60/gsmts_0707v050000p.pdf)
3. Third group is the different protocol stacks related commands. Like: IP,FTP, HTTP.
4. And there are the basic Hayes commands.

Usually in the AT user manuals the AT commands are separated by these main and sub-groups. 
As I saw in the [SIM900 AT User Manual](ftp://imall.iteadstudio.com/IM120417009_IComSat/DOC_SIM900_AT%20Command%20Manual_V1.03.pdf), the flow control related commands were under the V.25.ter standard. At the [SartGM862](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Cellular%20Modules/AT_Commands_Reference_Guide_r0.pdf)'s manul it can be found at the basic Hayes commands. (check for command: `AT+IFC`)

It is a good start if the modules support the same standards/protocols but the best option is to check both module's AT command manual and check the list of supported AT commands and the corresponding AT commands description to make sure about compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

The GSM modules all implement the same set of AT Commands. There can be some additional vendor specific commands, but the core set is common between the different manufacturers.